# SSRS Repeating group headers?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-grouping

I have this data

```
DateRecived      JObNumber         REcCnt
20130626          1234               1
20130627          1238               11
20130628          1240               2
20130629          1242               23
```

I applied the group by on **dateRecieved** in ssrs and get the output as

```
DateRecived      JObNumber         REcCnt
20130626          1234               1
20130627          1238               11
20130628          1240               2
20130629          1242               23
                  Total              37
```

But i want the output as

```
DateRecived      JObNumber         REcCnt
20130626          1234               1
                 Total               1
DateRecived      JObNumber         REcCnt
20130627          1238               11
                 Total               11
DateRecived      JObNumber         REcCnt
20130627          1240               2
                  Total              2
DateRecived      JObNumber         REcCnt
20130628          1242               23
                  Total              23
```

I don't know how to repeat the group header and calculate the sum for each group in **SSRS**  any help would be great .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a small example with some mock data that should be more or less analogous to your situation.

The dataset:

```
 Market    SubMarket
 ------    ---------
  A         1
  A         2
  A         3
  B         4
  B         5
  B         6
  B         7
```

Here are the steps I've taken to create the table:

1) Drag/drop a new, fresh table to the designer.

2) Drag/drop the SubMarket field to the first column.

3) Right-click the detail row and add a new parent group.

[image]

4) Group on Market and choose to add a group header row.

[image]

As you've already noted, SSRS "helps" and adds an extra column.

5) Right-click the extra (first) column and delete it.

6) Select the cell in the header row for the group and enter "[Market]", or pick it from the quick-list.

[image]

7) Finish up by filling in the other fields/columns/cells. For the header row drag/drop won't work, you'll have to pick the fields for that row yourself (or type 'em).

This is the resulting table in preview (with some emphasis on the header row):

[image]

For your solution you have to add all the other rows in detail section other than the fields on which you want to apply the group by.

Comment: This is a great trick!! I fought with trying to do this very thing for an hour!!

Answer (score 2):

You need a **group footer**. Currently you have *table footer* which shows grand total.

1. Right click the detail group section and select insert row.
2. Click outside group - below. (This will add a footer)
3. In the footer under `REccCt` and set the expression as =SUM(Fields!REcCnt.Value)

If you don't want to show the grand total 37 you can delete the *table footer* not the **group footer**  you just created.

**Update** Reread your question. You also need a **group header** along with group footer.