# Multivalued field representation in ssrs

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have a table with family details as below:

```
Name  Gender  Family_No Member_No

ABC   Male       1          1
XYG   Female     1          2
DFG   Male       1          1
```

and want to represent that in SSRS as below:

```
Family 1:
         Member 1:ABC, Male
         Member 2: XYZ, Female

Family 2:
         Member 1: DFG,Male
```

As you see Member field should repeat as it has multiple values.
I have done grouping and all but it is showing only 1st record.
I'm using ***SSRS 2008*** and database is **SQL Server**.

Comment: You need to _add a group header_. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18446245/2647648)

Comment: Thanks It Worked!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created Group header for the rows which needs to repeat and other rows excluded from the group